# I disabled IPv6 in my smartphone but nslookup returns ipv6

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ipv6

I use my mobile data and hotspot to my laptop, so my laptop uses the same internet as my mobile.

I recently disabled `IPv4/IPv6` and only enabled `IPv4` in my mobile data settings, but today is what happened in both Windows terminal and WSL:

```
C:\Users\Saeed> nslookup google.com
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    google.com
Addresses:  2001:4860:4802:32::78
          216.239.38.120
```

```
root@DESKTOP-9PR0R3P:~# nslookup google.com
Server:         192.168.0.1
Address:        192.168.0.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.239.38.120
Name:   google.com
Address: 2001:4860:4802:32::78
```

I also checked in my Windows internet settings and IPv6 is disabled (untick).

Why did this happen? Is my mobile not doing what he should?

Answer (score 2):

Not having IPv6 connectivity does not prevent software from asking DNS servers *about* IPv6 addresses. If you don't explicitly tell nslookup what DNS record type to query, it will always query for both `A` and `AAAA` record types, regardless of what protocol is used to deliver those queries to the server. (The DNS queries are being sent via IPv4, as you can see from the "Server Address" being an IPv4 address.)

Comment: That's weird in my mind, because I did disable IPv6 so that it won't lookup or anything with version 6.

Comment: Technically no, you only disabled the ability to send packets *via* IPv6... **Most** programs (that use OS-provided DNS services) will indeed stop making AAAA lookups when they see the lack of an IPv6 connection, but tools like `nslookup` are different – their purpose is to show results to the user instead of making connections, so they handle DNS entirely on their own (and they look up not only address records but any other type as well), and such tools prioritize showing consistent results regardless of system configuration.